# what is the result of multiplying array by 1

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to implement the [trading view Mihkel00 SSL Hybrid indicator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine/?id=PUB%3BZytqOjqg7LTtinPoslFgHUVp4BE0tgdZ) in C#.

At some point (line 211) the following two lines (in the SSL Hybrid script) are executed

```
open_pos =  open*1
close_pos = close*1
```

My understanding is that these two statements just multiply the array of values (open prices, close prices) by **1**, resulting in the same array values. So these two statements identical to:

```
open_pos =  open
close_pos = close
```

Assuming I am not wrong, I am asking why multiply array by 1?

Are there other side effects to that operation, except of creating a copy of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PineScript is really strange sometimes. It has a kinda of syntax sugar that omits a strange behavior: all declared variables become `series`.

Yes, variables could be used as `series` since all bars are processed in a linear sequence. And what we see as a `series` could be used as a variable, if no index is specified.

For example, `open` is a `float series`. You could access its indexes like `open[1]`, `open[10]`, etc. But if you try to compare it as you would do with a simple number like:

```pine
if open > 10
```

it would behave the exactly same as

```pine
if open[0] > 10
```

---

At your example, the snippet's author was just trying to make sure `open_pos` and `close_pos` would receive a `float`, and not an `series` type. But it's was not necessary.

If you run something like this, you could check for yourself:

```pine
//@version=5
strategy("demo", overlay=true)

open_pos_a = open * 1
open_pos_b = open 
open_pos_c = open[0]

plot(open_pos_a, color = color.black)
plot(open_pos_b, color = color.red)
plot(open_pos_c, color = color.green)
```

With the above example, you will see that the three series plotted has the same values for all datapoints.

Comment: `array`s and `series` are not the same. `[]` is used to access historical data of the `series` type. You must use `array.get()` to get the value of the element at the specified index of an array. `open * 1` will also return a `series` and not a simple `float`.

Comment: @vitruvius not sure I understand ...are you saying that @luizv answer is wrong? and if so - what is the purpose of `open * 1` ?

Comment: luizv,  following your explanation - is the following statement correct `open * 1 == open[0]` ?

Comment: I cannot think of any reason for that. It is the same if you do `open_pos =  open`.

Comment: Yes, and `open == open[0] == open * 1`. The snippet's author was trying to make sure the it's a float, not a series. As pointed by @vitruvius, it changes nothing for this case.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that I was talking about `series` type, not `arrays`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Tx. I tried your short script, indeed all values are equal. But actually I got lost now even more...On the one hand `plot` receive `series` as the first parameter. On the other hand you explain (might be I misunderstood) that  the two expressions `open * 1 , open[0]`  return a single `float` number.  What Am I missing?

Comment: "The snippet's author was trying to make sure the it's a float, not a series". This statement is not correct. `open * 1` will return a `series float`.

Comment: @vitruvius I believe it was his intention, even it’s effectively unnecessary. That’s the only explanation behind the `*1` code.

Comment: @OJNSim, yes, it return a float in that single execution of the script. But it’s a particularity of Pinescript that you can access past states of a variable simply using a index. 

For example, `open_pos` will be a `float series` and you could access `open_pos[1]` even if you declare it like `open_pos = 10.0`.

Comment: Tx. I also found [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) manual paragraph  discussing this.